# taskdef class weblogic.ant.taskdefs.webservices.servicegen.ServiceGenTask cannot be found

Tags: java, ant, weblogic, weblogic12c, weblogic11g

I am getting `taskdef class weblogic.ant.taskdefs.webservices.servicegen.ServiceGenTask cannot be found` error while trying to build my project. When googled I found that webservices.jar required to be build.

unable to find `webservices.jar` from `ws_home/server/lib folder`

I am using `weblogic 12.2.1.2.0`.

Comment: You will probably need to be more specific on the version release - e.g. 12.2.1.2 vs 12.1.2.  You may be trying to use something that isn't available in your release.

Comment: I am using 12.2.1.2.0

Comment: @vsfDawg any specific workaround need to be done for this.